# Using Qt 6 in Clang project under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, clang

I am trying to add the Qt 6 libraries to an existing Clang project.

I have downloaded the compile Qt libraries for MSVC. I have read they are ABI compatible with Clang. However I don't even come that far, as CMake is making me trouble setting some incompatible compiler flags `-permissive-` and `-Zc:__cplusplus`.

Here is the project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(drawing CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC TRUE)
find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets)

add_executable("drawing" drawing.cpp)
target_link_libraries("drawing" Qt6::Widgets)
```

I setup the environment as following:

```bash
set PATH=C:\Qt\6.3.1\msvc2019_64\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Tools\CMake_64\bin;C:\Qt\Tools\Ninja
set PATH=C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin;%PATH%
```

Then build the project as

```bash
cmake -H.. -B. -G Ninja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
ninja
```

This gives the following error:

```
[2/4] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/drawing.dir/drawing_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/drawing.dir/drawing_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\CLANG_~1.EXE -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_WIN64 -IC:/Users/brugg/Desktop/logiksim3/drawing/build/drawing_autogen/include -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/msvc2019_64/include/QtWidgets -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/msvc2019_64/include -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/msvc2019_64/include/QtCore -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/msvc2019_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/msvc2019_64/include/QtGui -O3 -DNDEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrt -Zc:__cplusplus -permissive- -utf-8 -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/drawing.dir/drawing_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\drawing.dir\drawing_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/drawing.dir/drawing_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.obj -c C:/Users/brugg/Desktop/logiksim3/drawing/build/drawing_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp
CLANG_~1: error: unknown argument: '-permissive-'
CLANG_~1: error: unsupported use of internal gcc -Z option '-Zc:__cplusplus'
[3/4] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/drawing.dir/drawing.cpp.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/drawing.dir/drawing.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~1\LLVM\bin\CLANG_~1.EXE -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -D_UNICODE -D_WIN64 -IC:/Users/brugg/Desktop/logiksim3/drawing/build/drawing_autogen/include -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/msvc2019_64/include/QtWidgets -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/msvc2019_64/include -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/msvc2019_64/include/QtCore -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/msvc2019_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc -isystem C:/Qt/6.3.1/msvc2019_64/include/QtGui -O3 -DNDEBUG -D_DLL -D_MT -Xclang --dependent-lib=msvcrt -Zc:__cplusplus -permissive- -utf-8 -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/drawing.dir/drawing.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\drawing.dir\drawing.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/drawing.dir/drawing.cpp.obj -c C:/Users/brugg/Desktop/logiksim3/drawing/drawing.cpp
CLANG_~1: error: unknown argument: '-permissive-'
CLANG_~1: error: unsupported use of internal gcc -Z option '-Zc:__cplusplus'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

What else do I need?

Answer (score 0):

This removes the invalid compiler flags again:

```
set_target_properties(Qt6::Core PROPERTIES INTERFACE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "")
```